# Group + sum with Javascript, Underscore or Lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am wondering how I could perform the following grouping and summing up with Underscore or Lodash.

> **MY ARRAY :**

```
[
{_id : "1", S : "2"},
{_id : "1", M : "4"},
{_id : "2", M : "1"},
{_id : "" , M : "1"},
{_id : "3", S : "3"}
]
```

> **DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
[
{_id : "1", M : "4", S : "2", Total: "6"},
{_id : "2", M : "1", S : "0", Total: "1"},
{_id : "3", M : "0", S : "3", Total: "3"},
{_id : "",  M : "1", S : "0", Total: "1"}
]
```

> What I have this far

I have a strong believe that I have done the following right this far, but I cannot figure out what I have put in ??

```
var groups = _.groupBy(MyArray, function(value){
            return value._id;
        });

        var data = _.map(groups, function(group){
            return {
                _id: group[0]._id,
                M:  ?? ,
                S:  ?? ,
                T:  ?? 

            }
        });
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have played around with underscore quite a long, but I cant figure out how to do this

Comment: What does Total represent?  From you desired output I don't get the algorithm.  Maybe typos?

Comment: @James yes, it was typos, now updated. total represents M+S

Comment: This really kills my head, I would appreciate any help: I know underscore can proceed this fairly easy with few lines of code, but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: You can do this in Vanilla JS by doing somehting like this:

`input.map(function(item, idx, arr) {
     var out = {};
     out = Object.assign(out, item);
     arr.forEach(function(item2, idx2, arr2) {
          if(item2._id === item._id && item2 !== item) {
               out["M"] = item2["M"] || "0";
          }
     });
     out["S"] = out["S"] || "0";
     out["M"] = out["M"] || "0";
     out["Total"] = Number(out["S"]) + Number(out["M"]);
     return out;
}).filter(function(item, idx, arr) {
    this[item._id] = (this[item._id] || 0) + 1;
    return this[item._id] <= 1;
}, {});`

Comment: I know it's not really answering your question but I hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with plain javascript, using [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) functions

```
var obj = {}

// arr is your first array
arr.forEach(function(a) {
    var t = obj[a._id];
    if (t) {
        t.M += a.M ? parseInt(a.M, 10) : 0;
        t.S += a.S ? parseInt(a.S, 10) : 0;
        t.Total = parseInt(t.M, 10) + parseInt(t.S, 10);
    } else {
        t = {};
        t._id = a._id;
        t.M = a.M ? parseInt(a.M, 10) : 0;
        t.S = a.S ? parseInt(a.S, 10) : 0;
        t.Total = parseInt(t.M, 10) + parseInt(t.S, 10);
        obj[a._id] = t;
    }
});

var res = Object.keys(obj).map(function (k) {
    return obj[k];
})

console.log(res);
```

Result:

```
[ { _id: '1', M: 4, S: 2, Total: 6 },
  { _id: '2', M: 1, S: 0, Total: 1 },
  { _id: '3', M: 0, S: 3, Total: 3 },
  { _id: '', M: 1, S: 0, Total: 1 } ]
```

Comment: please add the base to `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal in plain Javascript with a temporary object and some array methods.

```js
var data = [{ _id: "1", S: "2" }, { _id: "1", M: "4" }, { _id: "2", M: "1" }, { _id: "", M: "1" }, { _id: "3", S: "3" }],
    result = function (data) {                // immediately invoked function expression
        var r = [], o = {};                   // declare the result and temp object
        data.forEach(function (a) {           // iterate over data
            if (!o[a._id]) {                  // check if id in object
                o[a._id] = {                  // if not build new object
                    _id: a._id,               // with the wanted properties
                    M: 0,                     // _id, a value taken for the key, too
                    S: 0,                     // M and S initialized with 0
                    Total: 0                  // Total as well initialised with 0
                };                            // push the reference of object to result
                r.push(o[a._id]);             // while we reference an object, the values
            }                                 // are the same in object o and in array r
            ['M', 'S'].forEach(function (k) { // iterate over M and S, the keys to sum
                o[a._id][k] += +a[k] || 0;    // add truthy value or 0 to group
                o[a._id].Total += +a[k] || 0; // take value or the default value 0 with
            });                               // a logical or
        });                                   // end of iteration
        return r;                             // return result
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Damn, works like a charm! I cannot believe it works as I do not understand what happens between input and output :)

Answer (score 0):

A `lodash` `v3.10.1` compatible version using chained `groupBy()`, `thru()`, `keys()` `reduce()`, `find()` and `merge()`:

```
var ar = [{_id : "1", S : "2"},{_id : "1", M : "4"},
  {_id : "2", M : "1"},{_id : "" , M : "1"},{_id : "3", S : "3"}]

_(ar).groupBy('_id').thru(function(o){
  return _.keys(o).reduce(function(arr, key) {
    var r = {
      _id: key,
      S: parseInt((_.find(o[key], function(i){ return i["S"]}) || {S:0}).S, 10),
      M: parseInt((_.find(o[key], function(i){ return i["M"]}) || {M:0}).M, 10)
    };
    arr.push(_.merge(r, {Total: r.S+r.M}));
    return arr;
  }, [])
}).value();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [
    {_id : "1", S : "2"},
    {_id : "1", M : "4"},
    {_id : "2", M : "1"},
    {_id : "" , M : "1"},
    {_id : "3", S : "3"}
    ];

array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
      var existingObj = previousValue.find(function(obj){
          return obj._id == currentValue._id;
      });

      if(existingObj){
          Object.assign(existingObj, currentValue);
          existingObj.total = +(existingObj.M) + +(existingObj.S);
      }else{
          if(currentValue.M){
                currentValue.total = currentValue.M;
          }else if(currentValue.S){
              currentValue.total = currentValue.S;
          }
          previousValue.push(currentValue);
      }
     return previousValue; 
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty concise lodash solution:

```
_(data).groupBy("_id").map((group, id) => { //group is an array of items with the same id
    const mTotal = _.sum(_.map(group, (item) => parseInt(item.M) || 0));
    const sTotal = _.sum(_.map(group, (item) => parseInt(item.S) || 0));
    return {
         _id: id,
         M: mTotal.toString(),
         S: sTotal.toString(),
         Total: (mTotal + sTotal).toString()
    }
}).value() //End lodash chain
```

Sidenote: you're making things harder for yourself by not converting your strings to numbers.